# Subaru Legacy 2000 Factory Service Manual European version

Tags: subaru, service-manual

I have been looking for a long time for this manual but couldn't find it on the internet, I found the American version of it but it is not applicable with my Vehicle Id Number. Im looking for the european version for Subaru Legacy year 2000 wagon.
Do you guys have any idea where i can find it or who should i contact?

Comment: A dealer would be a good first place.

Comment: Was there a specific difference with the European model that you were looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

As you may have found https://techinfo.subaru.com has the official Factory Service Manuals (FSM's) at a price although these are generally provide US domestic market information.  I'll paste some links below that may have additional documents.

https://sl-i.net/FORUM/showthread.php?18087-Subaru-Factory-Service-Manuals-(FSM)-Every-Model-USDM-EU

https://jdmfsm.info/Auto/Japan/Subaru/